# Вывод данных из двух таблиц (php+mysql)

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу помощи с выводом данных из двух таблиц.
Нужно следующее:
Из таблицы **table_a** вывести колонки №1 *user_id*, №2 *user_name*, №3 *user_age*, №4 *user_email* и из таблицы **table_b** вывести в колонке №5 - *city*, а в колонке №6 - *gender*.
table_a.user=*table_b*.user_id

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SELECT</title>
        <style>
            td:nth-child(5),td:nth-child(6){text-align:center;}
            table{border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;}
            td, th{padding: 10px;border: 1px solid black;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'USER', 'PASS', 'DATABASE');
        mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_a, table_b WHERE table_a.user=user_id AND (meta_key='city' OR meta_key='gender') ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    
    try {
        echo "<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>meta_value</th>
                    <th>meta_key</th>
                </tr>";
        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["user_id"] . "</td>"; // №1 (table_a)
            echo "<td>" . $row["user_name"] . "</td>"; // №2 (table_a)
            echo "<td>" . $row["user_age"] . "</td>"; // №3 (table_a)
            echo "<td>" . $row["user_email"] . "</td>"; // №4 (table_a)
            echo "<td>" . $row["meta_value"] . "</td>"; // №5 (table_b)
            echo "<td>" . $row["meta_key"] . "</td>"; // №6 (table_b)
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error DB: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db = null;
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Данный вариант кода выводит данные в следующем виде:

```
| ID | Name | Age | Email       | meta_value | meta_key |
| -- | ---- | --- |------------ | ---------- | -------- |
| 1  | Joe  | 22  | joe@joe.com | Spb        | city     |
| 1  | Joe  | 22  | joe@joe.com | man        | gender   |
| 2  | Lui  | 25  | lui@lui.com | Msk        | city     |
| 2  | Lui  | 25  | lui@lui.com | man        | gender   |
| 3  | Sam  | 25  | joe@joe.com | Ekb        | city     |
| 3  | Sam  | 25  | joe@joe.com | woman      | gender   |
| 4  | Hue  | 25  | hue@hue.com | Spb        | city     |
| 4  | Hue  | 25  | hue@hue.com | man        | gender   |
| 5  | Pie  | 25  | pie@pie.com | Msk        | city     |
| 5  | Pie  | 25  | pie@pie.com | woman      | gender   |
```

**Нужно вывести данные так:**

```
| ID  | Name | Age | Email       | City       | Gender   |
| --- | ---- | --- | ----------- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1   | Joe  | 22  | joe@joe.com | Spb        | man      |
| 2   | Lui  | 25  | lui@lui.com | Msk        | man      |
| 3   | Sam  | 25  | joe@joe.com | Ekb        | woman    |
| 4   | Hue  | 25  | hue@hue.com | Spb        | man      |
| 5   | Pie  | 25  | pie@pie.com | Msk        | woman    |
```

Понимаю, что можно выгрузить данные из двух таблиц в третью (в каком угодно порядке), ну а потом уже выводить её целиком, но возможно ли именно как указано выше без создания новой таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.user_id, p.user_name, p.user_age, p.user_email,
               m1.meta_value as 'city', m2.meta_value as 'gender'
        FROM table_a p
        LEFT JOIN table_b m1
            ON p.user = m1.user_id AND m1.meta_key = 'city'
        LEFT JOIN table_b m2
            ON p.user = m2.user_id AND m2.meta_key = 'gender'
";
```

На сколько понял, данной операцией мы создаем псевдонимы для значений `meta_key` из колонки `meta_value` и выводим их в `city` и `gender` (без перезаписи базы, только на стороне клиента), т.е. переносим значения из СТОЛБЦА в СТРОКУ.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю так лучше написать запрос он будет более оптимальный

```
SELECT
    table_a.user_id,
    table_a.user_name,
    table_a.user_age,
    table_a.user_email,
    table_b.meta_value,
    table_b.meta_key
FROM
    table_a
JOIN table_b on
    table_b.user_id = table_a.user_id
WHERE
    meta_key = 'city'
    OR meta_key = 'gender'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ НО:
a) table_a.user=table_b.user_id
b) поясните пожалуйста, зачем перечислять колонки в sql когда они указаны в php?
c) к сожалению, задачу это не решает

Comment: 1)table_b.user_id = table_a.user_id вам нужно соединит таблицы для выборки. Если поля не подходят поменяйте на нужные вам. 2) Каждый запрос имеет время выполнения и лучше указывать конкретные поля которые вам нужны, а не тянуть всё из базы и нагружать её